# TTS issues over bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, text-to-speech, android-4.4-kitkat

Here's the problem.  When I use the code below to have a message read over over Bluetooth in my car on my previous phone read correctly (Galaxy S3).  I have since upgraded to the HTC One (M8) and this no longer works on Bluetooth.  The weird part though is that when I click on the google now button it will listen over Bluetooth correctly.  So my question is does anyone know of the code that is being used for Google Now listening functionality over Bluetooth.  Like i said before the code below has worked on most devices so something has changed on Kit Kat.  Please help if you can.

```
am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
am.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
am.setBluetoothScoOn(true);
am.startBluetoothSco();
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue in Kitkat. Try changing the target OS to 4.3 in the Manifest file and then run it on a Kitkat device, it worked for me.

Comment: I will definitely try this out this evening and let you know the results.  Thank you!

Comment: This did make a slight positive change.  Now it connects to Bluetooth but will instantly end the connection. I'm thinking this sounds a lot like the normal Kit Kat Bluetooth issues I have read about though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm was having the same exact problem. To build upon the previous answer, the target OS needs to be 17 or below. Specifically JELLY_BEAN_MR1 or below (aka Android 4.2, 4.2.2). Android APK version 18 and up DO NOT work due to this issue.

I believe this has to do with the following from the documentation of AudioManager.startBluetoothSco:

> NOTE: up to and including API version JELLY_BEAN_MR1, this method initiates a virtual 
>   voice call to the bluetooth headset. After API version JELLY_BEAN_MR2 only a raw SCO audio
>   connection is established.
>
> the stream type must be STREAM_VOICE_CALL 
>   the format must be mono
>   the sampling must be 16kHz or 8kHz
>
> The following restrictions apply on input streams:
>   the format must be mono
>   the sampling must be 8kHz

Comment: Thanks, any idea how to convert to mono and 8khz?

Comment: I don't get how this works because the google now functionality works perfectly fine through bluetooth on kit kat.

Comment: No - no idea.  when I figure it out I'll post here.  And I too am confused as to how Google Now is working.  I suspect they are changing the bit rate to 8 kHz and mono.